# How do I enable checking in selected directories?

Tags: cmake

How can I enable scanning clang-tidy only in selected directories? Now it checks all files *cpp, *hpp, but I only need in folders src/project and tests.

clang.cmake:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES *.cpp *.hpp)

add_custom_target(
        clang-format
        COMMAND /usr/bin/clang-format
        -style=file
        -i
        ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
)

add_custom_target(
        clang-tidy
        COMMAND /usr/bin/clang-tidy
        ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
        -config=''
        --
        -std=c++11
        ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
)
```

Comment: So change `${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}` to files only inside `src/project and tests.` ? What have you tried?

Comment: Write "no input files specified" and error in makefile. I changed file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES *.cpp *.hpp) to file(GLOB_RECURSE "../src/project/main")